# declare and delete this version of a 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

```
int *array[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    array[i] = new int[10];
//...
void passFunc(int *a[10]) //array containing pointers
{
    //...
}

passFunc(array);
```

Im trying to figure out how to declare and delete this version of a 2D array. I started using int ** array, but in order to make one section of code easier, I need to switch to *[]. Can anyone help me out? 
I have tried compiling my actual code (the above code is just an example), which looks like this:

`int* filedata[LENGTH] = new int*[LENGTH]; //ERROR: array must be initialized with brace- enclosed identifiers.`

EDIT: 
Thanks!

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> myvec(Y_SIZE, vector<int>(X_SIZE));` usage `myvec[y][x] = 123;` deletes itself automatically.

Comment: I am aware of vectors, and they are relatively easy to use for me, however, I would like to stick with the *[] version. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
 int** array = new int*[sizeX];
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i)
   array[i] = new int[sizeY];
```

To delete

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i)
   delete [] array[i];
delete [] array;
```

Comment: So what is the difference between saying *array[] and **array, assuming they are the same type?

Comment: Basically, you cannot use array[] in declaration without giving it a size but you can use array[] to declare a parameter to a function. Same for array[][].

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you want then the allocation and deallocation will look as

```
int ** filedata = new int * [LENGTH];

for ( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++ ) filedata[i] = new int [LENGTH];

//...

for ( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++ ) delete [] filedata[i];
delete [] filedata;
```

Comment: In your delete section I think you mean `delete [] filedata[i]`instead of `delete [] filedata[LENGTH]`
Same for the creation

Comment: @Valentin Clement Thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: So if I use ** it will be the same as *[]?

Comment: @Ashley It will not be the same. Bit you can use the same syntax to access elements filedata[ i ][ j ].

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version to the ones given:

```
 int** array = new int*[sizeX];
 int *pool = new int[sizeX * sizeY];
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i, pool += sizeY)
   array[i] = pool;
```

To delete:

```
 delete [] array[0];
 delete [] array;
```

The advantage of using this is:

1. Only two calls to `new[]` and `delete[]` are required, regardless of the number of columns.  In the previous answer, the number of calls to `new` and `delete` depend on the number of columns.  This reduces fragmentation, and also will probably give you a speed increase if the number of columns is very large.
2. The data is contiguous.  You can access any element in the 2d array from any other element using a simple offset.

The disadvantage is that the number of columns for each row needs to be the same, otherwise it becomes very difficult to maintain.